# Javascript truncate a word around search expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like your help by finding a smart truncate function that will do the following:

1. according to a search expression will truncate the sentence to a define length,
2. keep the search expression inside the truncated sentence.

for example:

```
var sentence = "As they rounded a bend in the path that ran beside the river, Lara recognized the silhouette of a fig tree atop a nearby hill. The weather was hot and the days were long. The fig tree was in full leaf, but not yet bearing fruit.
Soon Lara spotted other landmarks—an outcropping of limestone beside the path that had a silhouette like a man’s face, a marshy spot beside the river where the waterfowl were easily startled, a tall tree that looked like a man with his arms upraised";

var searchExpression = "tree";
var truncateLength = 20;
```

the result will be:

```
"the silhouette of a fig tree atop a nearby hill"
```

the word tree will be a part of the truncated sentence.

Are you familiar with a javascript code that capable of doing it ?

Thanks,

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/zQ4yP6/1

Comment: in your result how `truncateLength` works? it's the minimum length of characters after and before the keyword? Also, the word `tree` appears many times: do you need to retrieve the first occurence? Can you show your attempts please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best possible way. But here is a working code that might help.

```js
var sentence = "As they rounded a bend in the path that ran beside the river,Lara recognized the silhouette of a fig tree atop a nearby hill. The weather was hot and the days were long. The fig tree was in full leaf, but not yet bearing fruit.Soon Lara spotted other landmarks—an outcropping of limestone beside the path that had a silhouette like a man’s face, a marshy spot beside the river where the waterfowl were easily startled, a tall tree that looked like a man with his arms upraised";
var searchExpression = "tree";
var truncateLength = 20;

var index = sentence.indexOf("tree");

var leftIndex = index - (truncateLength);
var rightIndex = index + (truncateLength);
var result = sentence.substring(leftIndex - searchExpression.length , rightIndex + searchExpression.length);
alert(result);
```

Comment: is it possible to get a whole words and not part of words ?

Comment: @LiadLivnat You mean if the words are getting cut in half , get them in full ?

Comment: Here is the link to fiddle with required changes - https://jsfiddle.net/soorajchn/3k8yf03u/1/

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this.  I embedded georg's regex and made a javascript function out of it.

https://jsfiddle.net/94xh1umx/

**Javascript**:

```
function truncate(sentence, searchExpression, truncateLength) {
  var pattern = new RegExp("\\b.{1,"+truncateLength+"}\\b"+searchExpression+"\\b.{1,"+truncateLength+"}\\b","i");
    var res = sentence.match(pattern);
  console.log(pattern);
  return res;
}

var sentence = "As they rounded a bend in the path that ran beside the river, Lara recognized the silhouette of a fig tree atop a nearby hill. The weather was hot and the days were long. The fig tree was in full leaf, but not yet bearing fruit."+
"Soon Lara spotted other landmarks—an outcropping of limestone beside the path that had a silhouette like a man’s face, a marshy spot beside the river where the waterfowl were easily startled, a tall tree that looked like a man with his arms upraised";
var searchExpression = "tree";
var truncateLength = 20;


var result = truncate(sentence, searchExpression, truncateLength);

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".result").html(result);
});
```